# Default __str__ method for an instance

Tags: python, cpython

I have a class without a `str` or `repr` method. And when I call it:

```
>>> from ingest.tpr import TPR
>>> t=TPR()
>>> t # that is, "repr(t)"
<ingest.tpr.TPR instance at 0x101eb8518>
```

The default representation here seems to be something like:

```
"<${path_to_class} instance at ${memory_address}>"
```

Where is this default implementation supplied? And is the above the `__repr__` method or the `__str__` method -- I know it calls the `__repr__` method in the above, but are both the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods initialized to the same thing at the start, or does one simply call the other as a "fall-back". In other words, what does the default `__str__` and `__repr__` look like in python and where would that be defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t.__repr__` (which is what `repr(t)` calls) resolves to (assuming no other upstream definitions) `object.__repr__`, which is defined by the Python implementation (for example, https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3827)

Comment: Thanks -- could you provide a link to (any version of) python where that's defined? Also, does `__str__` have a separate definition, or does it just call `__repr__` as a default.?

Comment: @David542: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L3763

Comment: @user2357112 thanks -- wow, a lot of things that you'd never think of in the definition (I thought it would be one line). For example: `/* It is possible for a type to have a tp_repr representation that loops
       infinitely. */
    if (Py_EnterRecursiveCall(" while getting the repr of an object"))
        return NULL;`

Comment: @chepner: `PyObject_Repr` is the C API version of `repr`, not `object.__repr__`. The `object` implementation lives in `Objects/typeobject.c`.

Comment: @user2357112 You know, I've made that mistake more than once. <sigh>